# mongoose buffering timed out problems with mongodb in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express, mongoose

I have a backend node connected to mongodb with docker-compose. When I try to create a document I get the error "Error MongooseError: Operation `contacts.insertOne()` buffering out after 10000ms".

I tried connecting to a local mondb server and the document is created.

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: xxx
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db  
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    container_name: backend
    volumes:
      - "./backend:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
volumes:
  db:
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv/config')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION, 
    {useNewUrlParser: true}, () => {
        console.log("Connected to mongodb")
})

const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    phoneNumber:  {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contacts', ContactSchema)
```

Route:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const Contact = require('../models/Contact')

const router = Router()

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const contact =  new Contact({
      name: req.body.name,
      address: req.body.address,
      phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
      email:  req.body.email
    })
    console.log('contact--->', contact)
    const response = await contact.save()
    console.log("response --->", response)
    res.send('creeated')
    
    
  
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('Error ', error)
    res.json({message: error})
  }
  
})

module.exports = router
```

I try to create a document in the db and what I get now is an error: "Error MongooseError: Operation `contacts.insertOne()` buffering out after 10000ms"

Comment: looks like  you need to whitelisted IP

Comment: The mongodb database is running on a local docker, where do I add the whitelist ?